# Alert jquery function

Tags: jquery, function, tags

I'm creating a link in jquery when you click on another link.

The problem is that I want to generate an alert when you click on this new link, but does not trigger the action!

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    $("<div/>").html('<a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a>').appendTo("#results");
});

$('#remove').click(function() {
    alert('lol');
});​
```

link to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/LARef/

Comment: At the moment you bind the event handler to `#remove`, the element does not exist yet. Bind the event handler once the element was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use delegate

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    $("<div/>").html('<a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a>').appendTo("#results");
});

$(window).delegate('#remove','click',  function() {
    alert('lol');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LARef/1/

Answer (score 0):

At the time you run the

```
$('#remove').click(function() {
    alert('lol');
});
```

the `#remove` element does not exist yet.. (*as it is added when you click on the first link*)

use the `.delegate()` method (*or `.on()` if you upgrade your jquery to 1.7+*)

```
$('#results').delegate('#remove', 'click', function(){
    alert('lol');
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/LARef/2/

---

The equivalent for v1.7+ is

```
$('#results').on('click', '#remove', function(){
    alert('lol');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the event after you create element.
change your code to this and it will work :

```
$('#test').click(function ()
{
    $("<div/>").html('<a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a>').appendTo("#results");
    $('#remove').click(function ()
    {
        alert('lol');
    });
});
```